# MySql query keep running for a long time

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

Following query keep running for a long time and I'm using MySql 5.5.34 on XAMPP on Windows

```
SELECT 
      id_package, 
      pck.fk_sales_order, 
      pck.fk_picklist, 
      count(pci.id_package_item) as items, 
      pcs.status, 
      pcs.status_changed_at, 
      so.order_nr, 
      pkli.* 
   FROM 
      oms_package AS pck
         INNER JOIN oms_package_status AS pcs 
            ON pck.id_package = pcs.fk_package 
            AND pcs.is_current = 1
         INNER JOIN ims_sales_order AS so 
            ON pck.fk_sales_order = so.id_sales_order
         LEFT JOIN oms_package_item AS pci 
            ON pck.id_package = pci.fk_package 
            LEFT JOIN wms_picklist_item AS pkli 
               ON pci.fk_sales_order_item = pkli.fk_sales_order_item
              AND pci.fk_inventory  = pkli.fk_inventory
              AND pkli.fk_picklist_item_status = 5 
   WHERE 
          (    pck.isdeleted = 0 
            OR pck.isdeleted IS NULL ) 
      AND pci.isdeleted = 0
   GROUP BY 
      pck.id_package 
   ORDER BY 
      status_updated_at desc 
   LIMIT 
      20
```

This query is running on Linux and take about 2 minutes to give the result, but on my Windows machine it keep running for more thatn 2 hours without producing any result.

What may be the issue ? Is it on query or my local server ?

Here are the record Counts on the tables

oms_package - 181878,

oms_package_status - 718650,

ims_sales_order - 228907,

oms_package_item - 306966,

wms_picklist_item - 322947

Here is the EXPLAIN result
[image]

Comment: run explain. this may answer Your question

Comment: Yes I did, but this slowness only in my machine,

Comment: Can you tell us what are you trying to achieve with this Query? The Joins seem to be the issue, may be there is another way of achieving it?

Comment: paste here Your explain. Query runtime may vary because on many factors. it may depend on DB and SERVER configuration, number of processors, memory size, OS etc.

Comment: Ok, I'll paste the XAPLAIN result

Comment: I have added EXPLAIN result

Answer (score 1):

There is no single silver bullet to fix such a issue.

Step#1: I'd suggest to perform following steps and check the performance:
analyze table  oms_package;

analyze table  oms_package_status;

analyze table  ims_sales_order;

analyze table  oms_package_item;

analyze table  wms_picklist_item;

Step#2: Please check resource (CPU, RAM, Disk IO) usage in the system. You might be getting performance issue because of resource hit. Specially, I'd suggest verifying disk IOPs.

Step#3: I also would like to ensure sufficient indexes for the query. I couldn't figure out available indexes, please share ddl scripts for the tables associated with the query.

Answer (score 1):

I've SLIGHTLY updated your query by editing the post for readability purposes.  While doing so, it helps me see the relationships better too.  I also removed the "tic" marks as you only really need those when columns or tables are in conflict with "reserved words" and otherwise just clutter the readability of a query.

Your "WHERE" clause has an "and pci.isdeleted = 0" which will kill your "LEFT JOIN" turning into an "INNER JOIN" instead.  If you DID mean for it to remain a left-join, move the "and pci..." component to the left-join portion of the query.

As for indexing, I would suggest on your oms_package table an index on ( id_package, isdeleted, fk_sales_order, fk_picklist) so it is a covering index and optimized for your group by and where condition.

For your oms_package_status table, an index on ( is_current, fk_package )

For ims_sales_order, index on (  id_sales_order, order_nr )

For oms_package_item, index on ( fk_package )

For wms_picklist_item, index on (fk_picklist_item_status, fk_sales_order_item, fk_inventory)

Additionally, I suggest you might be running into a Cartesian result set killing your query time... And one final suggestion (last option), try adding "STRAIGHT_JOIN" keyword there have been many instances where it has SIGNIFICANTLY improved performance... other times has hindered... hence try it last as comparison.

select STRAIGHT_JOIN ... rest of query...